# Angular.js - 403 Forbidden access is denied

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express, ionic-framework

I know this might be very general but I need some help.

I have a job interview and they have asked me to clone a project and learn how it works - [Repository HUBTaxi-Server](https://github.com/tungtouch/HubTaxi-Server). I've never worked in something this large and im quite stuck.

I've done everything as explained in the repository but still can't make it work.

I've reached the manager-loggin of the app and is giving me a 403 forbidden access. [Printed Screen of the error i'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfGYE.jpg)

I guess has something to do with the Mongo database. I have little experience with this.

Answer (score 0):

403 means you are not allowed to see the page. The readme on github says the login and the password are both 'admin' Try that and see if you can login.

Comment: HI yes i've tried that. It's not telling me that is a wrong password either. Checked in the DB and the "admin" user exists. [Print Screen loggin succesfull (?)](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByIbQvdhdFYdcjZDUDI5bnROZnc)

Comment: here some [console errors :-)](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByIbQvdhdFYdck9jUkxVVW1QSDQ)

Comment: I think it's wiser if you read the manuals from the repository, or contact the authors.This is a really specific problem.

Comment: yeah, i've sent an email to him already hope he answers. Thanks for your time :)